# Excel - IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to do homework in Excel, but I have problem with one task which I have to do with `IF` function.

I have number series in a form "891206/2356". If the third number is 0 or 1, the result is man. If there is 5 or 6, the result is woman.

Do you have any suggestion how to solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I got to ask - what if the said digit is not 0, 1, 5 nor 6? Is it some kind of polygenderic creature? Sexless Ken/Barbie type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, Kudos for being honest about this being homework!!

Next, since it is homework, I won't give the exact answer, but I would look into the `mid` function and place that within an `if` statement.

Good luck to you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @astrak, for fun, also take a look at the `CHOOSE` function - it can be applied something like `=CHOICE(MID(YourStuff),"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")`

Answer (score 0):

`MID( your_cell , 3, 1)` will give you the 3rd character in the string.

Then, you can chain IF functions to do your tests:

```
IF( MID(...)="1", "man", IF( MID(...)="2", "man", IF(  ..etc.. )   )
```